# Type function that returns a function wrapper

Tags: python

I'm trying to annotate the return type of the function below:

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor
from typing import Callable

from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")


def make_run_in_executor(executor: Executor): # What to put here?
    def run_in_executor(
        func: Callable[_P, _R], *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs
    ) -> _R:
        return executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs).result()

    return run_in_executor
```

I tried `Callable[Concatenate[Callable[_P, _R], _P], _R]`, but got the following error from Pylance:

```
Expression of type "(func: (**_P@run_in_executor) -> _R@run_in_executor, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R@run_in_executor" cannot be assigned to return type "((**_P@make_run_in_executor) -> _R@make_run_in_executor, **_P@make_run_in_executor) -> _R@make_run_in_executor"
  Type "(func: (**_P@run_in_executor) -> _R@run_in_executor, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R@run_in_executor" cannot be assigned to type "((**_P@make_run_in_executor) -> _R@make_run_in_executor, **_P@make_run_in_executor) -> _R@make_run_in_executor"
```

Did I do it right and this is just a bug in Pylance? Or is there another way to type this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Callable` with a nested `Callable` to describe the return type of `make_run_in_executor`, if there is still an error it might be due to `Pylance` or your environment.

```
from concurrent.futures import Executor
from typing import Callable

from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")


def make_run_in_executor(executor: Executor) -> Callable[Concatenate[Callable[_P, _R], _P], _R]:
    def run_in_executor(
        func: Callable[_P, _R], *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs
    ) -> _R:
        return executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs).result()

    return run_in_executor
```